# Can I ask the following discussion question?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-questions

So I'm working through the textbook " Introducing Advanced Macroeconomics: Growth and Business Cycles" by Sorrenson. I have noticed that it's very equation and math heavy, while I do enjoy maths, it all seems so futile.

I am getting the feeling that working through this book is just teaching me how to manipulate equations and not really teaching me practical economics that I can use in research.

I wanted to hear people's thoughts on this, but not sure I can post it.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't really recommend that question on the main site as it is opinion based.
The reason why I think it is an opinion based question is due to the last point in your question.

> I am getting the feeling that working through this book is just teaching me how to manipulate equations and not really teaching me practical economics that I can use in research.
>
> **I wanted to hear people's thoughts on this, but not sure I can post it.**

However if you asked a question like:

> What is the basis for structural macroeconomic models like those shown in  "Introducing Advanced Macroeconomics: Growth and Business Cycles" by Sorrenson? how will an equation like X help me in developing my macroeconomic research skills?

I think it would be an appropriate question as it demands not a set of opinions but an answer instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to do just that.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to EconJohn's solution, you could post a [reference-request](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) question asking references that discuss the role of mathematics in economics. Many leading economists with extensive practical experience have written on the debate.